# Is there a way to change the severity of the message sent to the syslog daemon when a unit goes into a failed state?

Tags: linux, syslog, systemd, rsyslog

Is there a way to change the severity of the message sent to the syslog daemon when a unit goes into a failed state? Currently it's "warning" and I'd to change it to "error".